# How to group an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two arrays:

```
let props = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let values = ['a', 'f', 'k', 'd', 'l'];
```

I need to get an object like:

```
{
    "a": [
        {
            "b": "f",
            "c": "k"
        }
    ],
    "d": [
        {
            "e": "l"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i do that in Javascript? Thanks

Comment: What is the logic behind that object (its structure)?

Comment: It's a group of item characteristics.

Comment: For example:
props = ['Basic Properties', 'Property1', 'Property2', 'Additional Properties', 'Property 3']

Comment: and values = ['Basic Properties', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Additional Properties', 'Value 3']

Comment: @ManMale How are you delineating between the initial set of properties and the other?  This data structure is nonsense unless you can provide more context.

Comment: Why are the values of the `a` and `d` properties arrays when they only have one element? Why not just put the objects directly in them?

Comment: unless you need an answer for this exact array, this is going to basically be impossible to answer. you need to provide some context as to what the dataset is. for example, why are `a` and `d` keys and not `b` or `c`?

Comment: Guys, idk why you downvote the question, I am very new to Javascript

Comment: do the two arrays always have the same length?

Comment: @ManMale I can't speak for the others, but I downvoted the question because this data structure doesn't make any sense.  As imjared says, any code we give you would only work in this exact specific situation, and not applicable to whatever problem it is that you're trying to solve.  The fact that you're new to JavaScript isn't relevant... you should be able to provide a real example so we can help you.

Comment: 'a' and 'd' because props[i] = values[i];

Comment: Okay, will do next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach()`

```js
let props = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let values = ['a', 'f', 'k', 'd', 'l'];
let cur = props[0];
let res = {};
props.forEach((a,i) => {
  if(a === values[i]){
    cur = a;
    res[a] = {};
  }
  else{
    res[cur][a] = values[i]
  }


})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Not quite right. This is putting `b: f` and `c: k` in separate objects, not the same object.

Comment: Close. `res[a] = [{}]` and `res[cur][0][a] = values[i]`

Comment: He has an unnecessary array wrapped around the object.

Comment: @ManMale Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with my answer

Comment: How do i do that, i am new to StackOverflow :(

Comment: Oh, got it now, thank you again!